# why Notification Color different in Dark and Light mode?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

We use FCM Notification and set color in `AndroidManifest.xml` by `com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color` metadata but It have issue for us why Android Notification shows two different colors in Dark and Light mode.
Is there a requirement for color for that? I reed about Notification color in Android Doc but I did not catch.

[image: dark mode]
[image: light mode]

Comment: I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Android OS changes color bit when change mode.